# Search for lines not containing #instagram_h1 and #instagram_h2 but should contain #instagram_h3

Tags: python, regex

So I get a file from client like this (4 lines are displayed below)

```
Some text #instagram_h1 #instagram_h2 some more text #instagram_h3 more texts
Some text #instagram_h3 #instagram_h2 some more text #instagram_h1 more texts
Some text #instagram_h2 some more text #instagram_h3 more texts
Some text some more text #instagram_h3 more texts
```

I am looking to search for only lines which contain #instagram_h3 and discard lines which has any or both of #instagram_h1 and #instagram_h2. #instagram_h3 will be always present.

My attempt:

```
h1 = '#instagram_h1'
h2 = '#instagram_h2'
h3 = '#instagram_h3'
result = re.search(r"(!h1|!h2)", str)
print result
```

here result is always None. Can anyone please explain, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no regex `!` operator. What you can do instead is find line that *do* contain those strings, and then exclude them.

```
if re.search(r"#instagram_(h1|h2)\b", str):
    # no good!
```

Notice how I've added `\b` to prevent something like `#instagram_h123` from matching.

Alternatively, for a simple search like this you could skip regexes and check for the substrings directly.

```
if '#instagram_h1' in str or '#instagram_h2' in str:
    # no good!

# or

hashtags = ['#instagram_h1', '#instagram_h2']
if any(hashtag in str for hashtag in hashtags):
    # sorry!
```

Note that these simple tests will match `#instagram_123` or `#instagram_234`, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Coming from perl background, I assumed that python has ! (invert) as well. Lession learned.